How have multiple wildcards in angular routing-module
I move my project to standalone components and remove modules.
I end with an app-routing-module that includes all routes.
It used to call sub routing-modules with a wild card in each of them.
Now the most generic wild card overrides my less generic wildcards. How make it work as I don't want sub routing modules ?
Example :
{
    path: `specificPath/**`,
    redirectTo: `specificPath`,
    pathMatch: 'full',
},

{
    path: '**', // Overrides above route
    redirectTo: genericPath,
    pathMatch: 'full',
},


You can take advantage of url matcher which is just a function which does the same as path with wildcard, to handle this scenario.
If the value is returned then the redirect happens, else it will fallback to the default wild card!
full code
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, RouterModule, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { TestComponent } from './app/test/test.component';
import { QwertyComponent } from './app/qwerty/qwerty.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    <a routerLink="/specificPath/zxcv">specific route</a> | 
    <a routerLink="/test">some route</a>
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: 'test',
        component: TestComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'specificPath',
        component: QwertyComponent,
      },
      {
        matcher: specificPathMatcher,
        redirectTo: `specificPath`,
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'test',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ]),
  ],
});

export function specificPathMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  return url.length && url[0]?.path?.toLowerCase() === 'specificpath'
    ? { consumed: url }
    : null;
}

Stackblitz Demo
